Can any electric rockets utilize in-situ asteroid materials as reaction mass?
Asteroids have materials of high value with potential for commercial mining but the rocketry required to support it appears to be one of the biggest challenges, with high costs. In mass terms the fuels or reaction mass for getting to and from the asteroid represent one of, if not the largest payload requirements; any rockets that require fuels or reaction mass sourced from Earth will be at a disadvantage compared to those that can utilize asteroid materials. High reliability and durability rockets that need little ongoing supply from Earth seems required to improve the cost effectiveness, which is essential to commercial viability.
Chemical rockets using H2/O2 appear possible using electrolysis of water extracted from carbonaceous material but, if I understand correctly, Hydrogen fuel needs very large tanks and other challenges and have lower efficiencies than solar electric (arc-jets?), so have made the question about the latter. Are there any combinations of rocket type and rocket "fuel" that could rely on relatively simple to process in-situ resources?

A mass driver can use electricity plus any material to provide thrust.
A mass driver uses a linear motor to accelerate a cart that contains a bucket filled with (in this case) asteroid rubble. At the end of the track, the cart is slowed down, the rubble keeps going.
The drawback of this approach is that you create lots of space debris.

You would not need to launch loose rubble, you could launch bags of rubble or bricks made out of compressed rubble to avoid creating a debris field.

I think the ISP would be pretty terrible, although you could point the exhaust at somewhere you want the material to go: propel yourself while delivering metal somewhere else.

Bricks would reduce the number of objects a bit, but the common concept of a mass driver is operated like a machine gun, with a steady stream of projectiles leaving the barrel. Isp depends on exhaust velocity, and if the mass driver is large enough that number can get pretty high. A few years ago the US Navy tested a prototype railgun with an exhaust velocity of 3400 m/s.

Can't use an Ion drive instead and propel broken down stuff far away?

Not an option that sprang to my mind, but, more developed, could answer. How is the efficiency of such hypothetical rockets compare to examples of electric propulsion? eg arc-jets with 16,000 m/s exhaust velocity (using Hydrogen as RM, that could be made but hard to carry). Ammonia is another RM used. An aside - if arc-jets dissociate the RM to plasma do combustible RM materials waste a lot of energy breaking such molecules like H2 apart and work better with something exothermic?

@Vorac - something inert perhaps.

@KenFabian no, I mean IF you have infinite electricity you can certainly break stuff down. Be it electrolysis, be it an ion drive that is aimed to the inside - at those powers hull integrity shouldn't be a problem. And then a second ion drive using the byproducts.  Dunno, this is drifting into worldbuilding.SE territory.

This does not directly answer the question, since the question specifies "electric rockets". However, electricity is in short supply in the asteroid belt due to the low intensity of sunlight for solar panels.
In this application, an alternative to electric rockets is solar thermal rockets, using in situ water as reaction mass. In the asteroid belt, low solar intensity is an issue (as it is for solar panels).
According to the Wikipedia article on solar thermal rockets
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_thermal_rocket

Solar thermal propulsion is also a good candidate for use in reusable
inter-orbital tugs, as it is a high-efficiency low-thrust system that
can be refuelled with relative ease.

Hydrogen as reaction mass gives high isp (1000+) but, as you pointed out, has storage issues.
Water has lower isp(190) but is potentially obtainable in situ from comet cores.

A solar-thermal propulsion architecture outperforms architectures
involving electrolysis and liquification of hydrogen from water by
more than an order of magnitude, since electrolysis requires heavy
power generators, whereas distillation only requires a simple and
compact heat source (either nuclear or solar); so the propellant
production rate is correspondingly far higher for any given initial
mass of equipment. However its use does rely on having clear ideas of
the location of water ice in the solar system, particularly on lunar
and asteroidal bodies, and such information is not known, other than
that the bodies within the asteroid belt and further from the Sun are
expected to be rich in water ice


Water should be available from carbonaceous type asteroid material - heating releases it - a reason a water shortage in The Expanse was a bit silly. Asteroids are found a lot closer than the asteroid belt, including Earth crossing orbits and orbits closer to the sun than Earth's; I would target them. Excellent solar energy resources. Water as RM was my very first thought but even for Near Earth Objects there will be a lot of delta-v required (Earth's gravity well) and I passed over the thermo-electric steam rocket as probably too inefficient; I'd be happy to be wrong.
